# Loudest Piezo with low voltage and current?

Tags: arduino, low-power, bluetooth-low-energy, piezo

I am making a board which will communicate wirelessly with a smart phone. When I send a specific command, I want it to sound an alarm to the user, making it able to be found when lost. I've got everything working with the device and I got the piezo buzzer to sound.

Problem is the piezo is quiet with it's 3v nominal voltage.. Any solutions towards a louder device that's small enough for one to wear on their keychain?

Comment: How loud do you want it?

Comment: Piezo sounders have a resonant frequency. If you oscillate it at that frequency you will get much more volume.

Comment: Piezo noisemakers are a flat diaphragm mounted over top of a resonant cavity.  The peizo element has a natural resonant frequency and the cavity is tuned to that same frequency.  You may not be operating your piezo sounder at its' correct frequency.  Or: you may need a better sounder.  It's sorta hard for us to tell right now.

Comment: A side note, I would also recommend pulsing the sound. At the higher frequencies piezo transducers are likely to output, people will have a hard time localizing it.

Answer (score 1):

When a piezo buzzer is not delivering enough volume, the most like root cause is one of the following:

- **Input signal is too weak** A signal may need an amplification stage before the piezo (even a venerable LM386 or similar would do)
- **Response is poor for input signal frequency** piezo buzzers typically work best over quite a limited band, say 2-5kHz with a peak around 4kHz.
- **The particular piezo component is not up to the job** 3V may be at the lower end of what they need to drive a decent sound. Use a test signal to verify it can actually generate the volume you are after. It might just be a dud unit, or maybe another brand/model would work better. Check the datasheet if possible (although I know for piezo buzzers they can be hard to find and verify they apply to the unit in your hand!).

NB: This [Peizoelectric Audio Components Application Manual](http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/sound/p15e.ashx) by Murata is one of a few that include a some good details of how to drive peizos and considerations that apply.